# Detatch and delete PublicIP from Azure network inferface using .NET SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I'm looking into an example of how to use the Azure .NET SDK to detach a Public IP object from a network interface belonging to an Azure VM.

The idea would be to delete the public IP when the VM is deallocated, so that we do t unnecessarily consume the public IP quota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Network Interface has some IP configurations. Every IP configuration has one public IP address. So if we want to detach  Public IP from Azure Network Interface, we just need to remove public IP from the IP configuration. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses)

Regarding how to implement it with Net, we can use the sdk [Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net). The detailed steps are as below

a. create a service principal  (I use Azure CLI to do that)

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# the sp will have Azure Contributor role
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric"
```

[image]

2. Code

```
 AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                      clientId, // the sp appId
                      clientSecret, // the sp password
                      tenantId, // the sp tenant  
                       AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure()
                                                   .Authenticate(credentials)
                                                   .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);// the subscription you use
            var resourceGroupName = "testapi06"; // the vm resource group name
            var vmName = "testvs";// the vm name
            //get the Azure VM
            var vm =await azure.VirtualMachines.GetByResourceGroupAsync(resourceGroupName, vmName);
            // get Azure VM's network interfaces
            foreach (var nicId in vm.NetworkInterfaceIds) {

                var nic = await azure.NetworkInterfaces.GetByIdAsync(nicId);
                // get network interface's ip configurations
                foreach (var r in nic.IPConfigurations)
                {
                    var ipConfigNmae = r.Key;
                    // detach a Public IP object from  network interface
                    await nic.Update().UpdateIPConfiguration(ipConfigNmae)
                                          .WithoutPublicIPAddress()
                                          .Parent()
                                       .ApplyAsync();

                    // delete public ip
                    var publicIpId = r.Value.GetPublicIPAddress().Id;
                    await azure.PublicIPAddresses.DeleteByIdAsync(publicIpId);
                };


            };
```